# Why spring boot update method create new record

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created update method in spring boot. It creates new record instead of update the record.

Tried code:

controller:

```
@PutMapping("update/{id}")
public Users updateUser(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Users user) {
    user.setFname(user.getFname());
    user.setLname(user.getLname());
    user.setAddress(user.getAddress());
    user.setTelno(user.getTelno());
    return serveiceClass.updateUserbyId(id, user);
}
```

service:

```
public Users updateUserbyId(Integer id, Users users) {
    return repositoryInterface.save(users);
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not checking if user is present or not and you creating new record by calling `save` method. `save` method always insert new row if id in given object is not present in DB, in your case `user` is having id `0` I guess, thats why it is inserting new record. You need to fetch the User from given id and update the existing record in DB.

Create one more method in service class

```
        public Users getUserById(Integer id) {
             return repositoryInterface.findById(id).orElse(null);
        }
```

And then..

```
       @PutMapping("update/{id}")
       public Users updateUser(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Users user) {
           Users userExisting =  serveiceClass.getUserById(id);
           if(userExisting  == null){
              throw Exception("User Not Found");
            }
          userExisting.setFname(user.getFname());
          userExisting.setLname(user.getLname());
          userExisting.setAddress(user.getAddress());
          userExisting.setTelno(user.getTelno());
          return serveiceClass.updateUserbyId(userExisting);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

one of my junior was facing this issue and when checked, i found he was updating the primary key/id of the user too. this might not be the acceptable solution, but please check your id (you must not be updating your id/primary key while you're updating the user)

Answer (score -2):

You can try to replace the save function with `SaveOrUpdate`

```
public Users updateUserbyId(Integer id, Users users) {
    return repositoryInterface.SaveOrUpdate(users);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).